# How to integrate National Identification Authority (NIDA) API for Tanzania?

Tags: android

I want to integrate National Identification Authority (NIDA) API for Tanzania in my Android application. In my application, user will enter their NIDA number and I want to retrieve user information according to NIDA number.

I have just one PDF file to guide me, it says that I need to have 3 to 4 certificates i.e. Serve CA Certificate n etc. And after that 4 to 5 encryptions are needed to implement to request NIDA API. And no other information are given like what is the end point for the request?

As I couldn't find anything else on the internet related to NIDA API call, I couldn't even start the programming! So I have not done any coding yet, so not sharing any codes.

If anyone knows anything about the NIDA API call, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I will edit the answer, as i want to implement the API in android only.

Comment: I should say that this question still doesn't conform to [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @PriyankaAlachiya Looking to integrate same on Web platform so do let me know if you find anything important.

Comment: Sure @ParthGoswami.

Comment: @PriyankaAlachiya Did you manage to integrate the Tanzanian Nida Api in your App ?

Comment: @salimsaid My web team has integrated NIDA api successfully. Though we are stuck at Bio-metric verification stage.

Comment: @PriyankaAlachiya is your team based in Tanzania ?

Comment: @salimsaid No. It is in India.

Comment: I think the best approach will be to contact NIDA and have a formal request to use their API (since it exposes sensitive personal information). When you are permitted, I'm quite sure they will give you the access credentials and necessary documentations

Comment: Yes @landrykapela, i was able to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @PriyankaAlachiya i found your question too late.  Can you help with any documentation if you have

Comment: @eli Sorry i can't provide you any documents related to NIDA

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This question's answer needs official documents which are not public

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NIDA does not have a developer portal or documentation online one has to contact them and ask for access. However I heard once in the news that "NIDA will start charging entities who are using its Data - Ref

https://www.thecitizen.co.tz/tanzania/news/nida-to-start-charging-entities-using-its-data-2712730"

But there is no official portal for accessing their API. The legal way to obtain access to their API is to visit their office for Technical Support.

That being said, a simple quick hack solution will be to use existing private sector that uses NIDA API to your advantage since it's REST Full API without verification token or access token

Here is an example :
Where NIN = National Id Number. Eg: 19760517372270000217

```
`curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Length: 0' -H "Content-type: application/json" 'https://ors.brela.go.tz/um/load/load_nida/{NIN}`
```

You should expect a json data object in return if the ID is valid or exist

Comment: Thanks @Emanuel for the information. We already contacted their technical support and found the APIs.

Comment: @PriyankaAlachiya did they charge you anything?